# How do I detect when a user changes the month or week in JTCalendar?

Tags: ios

Does anyone know how to detect month or week changes in **JTCalendar**?  I don't see any events for that in the documentation.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JTCalander delegate method

```
- (void)calendarDidLoadPreviousPage:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar{

}

- (void)calendarDidLoadNextPage:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar{

}
```